# Using R in order to fill NA values with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello I hava a datafram such as

```
> tab
   COL1                          COL2 COL3 COL4
1    G1     SEQ1_10-67_-__Canis_lupus    A    B
2    G1    SEQ4.1_90-345_-__Elpah_bis    C    D
3    G1  SEQA.B_34-50_-__Felis_cattus <NA> <NA>
4    G1  SEQA.B_34-50_-__Felis_cattus <NA> <NA>
5    G1 SEQA.A-2-BICs_-__Felis_cattus    E    F
6    G1  SEQA.A_10-30_-__Felis_cattus <NA> <NA>
7    G1  SEQA.A_34-50_-__Felis_cattus <NA> <NA>
8    G1 SEQA.B-2-BICs_-__Felis_cattus    L    P
9    G2  SEQA.A_60-79_-__Felis_cattus    K    L
10   G2  SEQA.A_34-50_-__Felis_cattus    M    N
11   G2     SEQ3_10-67_-__Lupus_lupus <NA> <NA>

> dput(tab)
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor"), COL2 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("SEQ1_10-67_-__Canis_lupus", 
"SEQ3_10-67_-__Lupus_lupus", "SEQ4.1_90-345_-__Elpah_bis", "SEQA.A_10-30_-__Felis_cattus", 
"SEQA.A_34-50_-__Felis_cattus", "SEQA.A_60-79_-__Felis_cattus", 
"SEQA.A-2-BICs_-__Felis_cattus", "SEQA.B_34-50_-__Felis_cattus", 
"SEQA.B-2-BICs_-__Felis_cattus"), class = "factor"), COL3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "C", 
"E", "K", "L", "M", "NA"), class = "factor"), COL4 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("B", "D", 
"F", "L", "N", "NA"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

and I would like to fill the NA values in `COL3` and `COL4`

The idea is for each `COL1` groups, if a `COL2 value` contains the `-BICs- pattern, then I extract the part before the first` -`and look within the groups if other`COL2 values`have the same pattern before the first`-`too.

Here in the exemple there is the pattern `-BICs`in line3 `SEQA.A-2-BICs_-__Felis_cattus`

the part before the first `-` is : `SEQA.A`

and

`lines 4` and `5` have the same `SEQA.A` in their string:

1. **SEQA.A***10-30*-__Felis_cattus
2. **SEQA.A***34-50*-__Felis_cattus

   then I add to them the `COL3` and `COL4` values of the `line3` and get an expected output:

```html
        COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
    G1 SEQ1_10-67_-__Canis_lupus   A B
    G1 SEQ4.1_90-345_-__Elpah_bis C D
    G1 SEQA.B_34-50_-__Felis_cattus L P
    G1 SEQA.B_34-50_-__Felis_cattus L P
    G1 SEQA.A_10-30_-__Felis_cattus E F
    G1 SEQA.A_34-50_-__Felis_cattus E F
    G2 SEQA.A_60-79_-__Felis_cattus K L
    G2 SEQA.A_34-50_-__Felis_cattus M N
    G2 SEQ3_10-67_-__Lupus_lupus   <NA> <NA>
```

and I also remove the line3 that had the `-BICs`pattern.

Does someine have an idea using for exemple dplyr ?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `fill` after grouping by 'COL1' and a grouping column created based on the prefix in 'COL2', then `fill` the values in 'COL3' and 'COL4' to change the NA with previous non-NA element, `ungroup`, and `filter` out the row with 'BICs' from 'COL2'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tab %>% 
  group_by(COL1, grp = str_remove(COL2, "[-_].*")) %>% 
  fill(c(COL3, COL4), .direction = 'downup') %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp) %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(COL2, "-BICs"))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  COL1  COL2                         COL3  COL4 
#  <fct> <fct>                        <fct> <fct>
#1 G1    SEQ1_10-67_-__Canis_lupus    A     B    
#2 G1    SEQ4.1_90-345_-__Elpah_bis   C     D    
#3 G1    SEQA.B_34-50_-__Felis_cattus L     P    
#4 G1    SEQA.B_34-50_-__Felis_cattus L     P    
#5 G1    SEQA.A_10-30_-__Felis_cattus E     F    
#6 G1    SEQA.A_34-50_-__Felis_cattus E     F    
#7 G2    SEQA.A_60-79_-__Felis_cattus K     L    
#8 G2    SEQA.A_34-50_-__Felis_cattus M     N    
#9 G2    SEQ3_10-67_-__Lupus_lupus    O     P
```

---

Or use `mutate_at`

```
tab %>% 
   group_by(COL1, grp = str_remove(COL2, "[-_].*")) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(COL3, COL4), ~ replace(., is.na(.),
           .[str_detect(COL2, "-BICs")])) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp) %>%
   filter(!str_detect(COL2, "-BICs"))
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not take into account the containt in COL2 before the first `-`that should be the same as the one with the `-BICs`pattern

Comment: @Grendel now, it does

Comment: but where is the part where it take into account the `SEQA.A`part ?

Comment: @Grendel are you saying that lines 3 to 7 belong to same group because it has `SEQA.A`

Comment: I updated the exemple to add more exemple, no the groups are defined by the `COL1 `only, I just say that `line3` and `4` got the `E` and `F` values because they share `SEQA.A `with `SEQA.A-2-BICs_-__Felis_cattus`

Comment: @Grendel my doubt is are you matching the prefix 'SEQA.A' as common one

Comment: I'm matching the prefix that can cange depending on what prefix is present : here we have SEQA.A and SEQA.B for instance

Comment: @Grendel can you check my update.  If there is an NA, by replacing with 0, cumsum returns the previous cumsum value

Comment: thank you but the code seems to also fill other NA columns, I updated the exemple where now line `11` has `COL3 and 4` with `NA` and because they do not have `BICs` with a `SEQ3` value match they stay that way